# How to implement a low pass filter over an image in the frequency domain with the Discrete Fourier Transform?

Tags: java, image, image-processing, fft, imagefilter

I'm trying to implement a 2d fourier transform  on an image. I have it so my DFT and inverse DFT work on an image. But when I apply the filter, by multiplying the complex numbers, and inverse the result I just get image noise.

Here is my 2d DFT

```
public void dft(double[][] inreal, double[][] inimag) {
int n = inreal.length;

double[][] tempreal = new double[n][n];
double[][] tempimag = new double[n][n];
realArray = new double[n][n];
imagArray = new double[n][n];

  for(int row = 0; row < n; row++) {  
    for (int col = 0; col < n; col++) {  
        double sumreal = 0;
        double sumimag = 0;
        for (int t = 0; t < n; t++) {  
            double angle = 2 * Math.PI * t * col / n;
            sumreal +=  inreal[row][t] * Math.cos(angle) + inimag[row][t] * Math.sin(angle);
            sumimag += -inreal[row][t] * Math.sin(angle) + inimag[row][t] * Math.cos(angle);
            
        }
        //System.out.println("r" + row + " " + "c" + col + " " + sumreal + " " + sumimag);
        tempreal[row][col] = sumreal;
        tempimag[row][col] = sumimag;
    }
}
    
    //now do it over the columns
 for (int col = 0; col < n; col++) {
    for (int row = 0; row < n; row++) {  // For each output element
        double sumreal = 0;
        double sumimag = 0;
        for (int t = 0; t < n; t++) {  // For each input element
            double angle = 2 * Math.PI * t * row / n;
            sumreal +=  tempreal[t][col] * Math.cos(angle) + tempimag[t][col] * Math.sin(angle);
            sumimag += -tempreal[t][col] * Math.sin(angle) + tempimag[t][col] * Math.cos(angle);
        }
        realArray[row][col] = sumreal;
        imagArray[row][col] = sumimag;
        //System.out.println(realArray[row][col] + " " + imagArray[row][col] + "i");
    }
 }
```

}

And here is my inverse DFT

```
public void inverseDFT(double[][] inRealArray, double[][] inImagArray) {
 int n = realArray.length;
    outRealArray = new double[n][n];
    outImagArray = new double[n][n];
    outputarray = new int[n][n];
    
    double[][] tempreal = new double[n][n];
    double[][] tempimag = new double[n][n];
 
    for (int col = 0; col < n; col++) {
        for (int row = 0; row < n; row++) {   // For each output element
           double sumreal = 0;
           double sumimag = 0;
           for (int t = 0; t < n; t++) {  // For each input element
               double angle = 2 * Math.PI * t * row / n;
               sumreal +=  inRealArray[t][col] * Math.cos(angle) - inImagArray[t][col] * Math.sin(angle);
               sumimag +=  inRealArray[t][col] * Math.sin(angle) + inImagArray[t][col] * Math.cos(angle);
        
           }
           //System.out.println("r" + row + " " + "c" + col + " " + sumreal + " " + sumimag);
           tempreal[row][col] = sumreal;
           tempimag[row][col] = sumimag;
       }
   }

    //now do it over the columns
    for(int row = 0; row < n; row++) {  
        for (int col = 0; col < n; col++) {  // For each output element
           double sumreal = 0;
           double sumimag = 0;
           for (int t = 0; t < n; t++) {  // For each input element
               double angle = 2 * Math.PI * t * col / n;
               sumreal +=  tempreal[row][t] * Math.cos(angle) - tempimag[row][t] * Math.sin(angle);
               sumimag +=  tempreal[row][t] * Math.sin(angle) + tempimag[row][t] * Math.cos(angle);
           }
           outRealArray[row][col] = sumreal / (n * n);
           outImagArray[row][col] = sumimag / (n * n);
           outputarray[row][col] = (int)Math.abs(outRealArray[row][col]);
           //System.out.println(outRealArray[row][col] + " " + outImagArray[row][col] + "i");
       }
  }
    
}
```

The image goes through and comes back the same.
I shifted the image to the center and got the spectral image to test if it works.

[image]

[image: This is the magnitude of the complex number and shifted to the center]

This is the magnitude of the complex number and shifted to the center

[image]

The Low Pass Filter

[image]

The Filter put through the DFT.

Here's my code to multiply the two.

```
    public void applyLowPassFilter(String filename, double[][] realArray, double[][] imagArray) throws IOException {
    ReadPGMFile readPGM = new ReadPGMFile(filename);
    double[][] filterArrayR = readPGM.loadArray();
    double[][] filterArrayI = new double[filterArrayR.length][filterArrayR.length];
    
    FourierTransform ft = new FourierTransform();
    ft.dft(filterArrayR, filterArrayI);
    filterReal = ft.getRealArray();
    filterImag = ft.getImagArray();
    
    int n = realArray.length;
    resultRealArray = new double[n][n];
    resultImagArray = new double[n][n];
    
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        int colValue = 0;
        int rowValue = 0;
        for(int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
         if(j < n / 2 ){
             colValue = (n / 2) - j;
         } else {
             colValue = (n - 1) - (j - ((n - 1) / 2));
         }
         if (i < n / 2) {
             rowValue = (n / 2) - i;
         } else {
             rowValue = (n - 1) - (i - ((n - 1) / 2));
         }
            
            
            resultRealArray[i][j] = realArray[rowValue][colValue] * filterReal[i][j] - imagArray[rowValue][colValue] * filterImag[i][j];
            resultImagArray[i][j] = realArray[rowValue][colValue] * filterImag[i][j] + imagArray[rowValue][colValue] * filterReal[i][j];
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

This is the result that I am getting. Sorry for the long post. If anyone has any insights I would appreciate them. I've been struggling with this for a few weeks now.

Comment: How do you know that your DFT and Inverse DFT work? Do you have some test data you tried? I would first make sure that these work using a very simple, trivial example or comparing it with a known tested implementation.

Comment: I put the lady image through the dft. I then took the frequency data and put it through the inverse and got the same image back. That works. This is a common image processing image - so the spectrum image is online and mine appears to very similar to what I've seen.

Comment: are you inverting the multiplication? otherwise it probably has to do with your display technique  and how you read the PGM filter etc

Comment: not sure what you mean. by "inverting  the multiplication" - do I put the result back through the dft inverse. yes, i use the inverse.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the code I use to test it:

```
      int[] pix=bim.getRGB(0, 0, wc, hc, null, 0, wc);
      double[][] ri=new double[hc][hc], ii=new double[hc][hc], ro=new double[hc][hc], io=new double[hc][hc];
      for(i=0; i<hc; i++)
      for(j=0; j<hc; j++) {
        int rr=(pix[i+j*wc]&0x00ff0000)>>16, rg=(pix[i+j*wc]&0x0000ff00)>>8, rb=pix[i+j*wc]&0x000000ff;
        ri[i][j]=0.2126*rr+0.7152*rg+0.0722*rb;
      }
      double[][] ff=new double[hc][hc];
      ff[hc/2][hc/2]=ff[hc/2][hc/2+1]=ff[hc/2][hc/2-1]=ff[hc/2+1][hc/2]=ff[hc/2-1][hc/2]=1;
      // ff[hc/2][hc/2]=ff[hc/2][hc/2+1]=ff[hc/2][hc/2-1]=ff[hc/2+1][hc/2]=ff[hc/2-1][hc/2]=ff[hc/2-1][hc/2-1]=ff[hc/2-1][hc/2+1]=ff[hc/2+1][hc/2-1]=ff[hc/2+1][hc/2+1]=0.125;
      filterDFT(ff, ri, ro, io);
      int[] pix2=new int[hc*hc];
      for(i=0; i<hc; i++)
      for(j=0; j<hc; j++) pix2[i+j*hc]=0xff000000|(int)Math.abs(ro[i][j]);
      BufferedImage b2=new BufferedImage(hc, hc, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
      b2.setRGB(0, 0, hc, hc, pix2, 0, hc);
```

Now b2 is your image; and it shows well - you have to reshuffle the quadrants.

Therefore I suggest you take a second look at what your filter reading downloads.

Comment: i think you are right. I'm not shifting the quadrants correctly. I'm trying to work out how to do that.